# Pre-defining variables

Tags: ruby, variables

This is my class structure:

```
class Commodity
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  class PriceSeries
    def initialize(name)
      @name = name
    end
  end
end
```

I want to instantiate the `Commodity` class:

```
gold = Commodity.new("gold")
```

then instantiate the `PricePoint` class:

```
gold.xau = Commodity::PriceSeries.new("gold")
```

It seems that I can only do this with an attribute accessor called `xau` in the gold class. Is this the only way to define that variable?

```
def xau
  xau
end
```

I feel like this shouldn't be a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a lot of ways to do it, but [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) is by far the simplest:

```
class Commodity
  attr_accessor :xau
end

gold = Commodity.new("gold")
gold.xau = some_value
```

What `attr_accessor :xau` does is defines a `xau=` method that assigns its argument to the instance variable `@xau`, and another method `xau` that returns the value of `@xau`. In other words, it basically does this:

```
class Commodity
  # Setter
  def xau=(value)
    @xau = value
  end

  # Getter
  def xau
    @xau
  end
end
```

For convenience and readability, Ruby lets you put whitespace before the `=` in `gold.xau = foo`, but in fact it's the same as the method call `gold.xau=(foo)`.

Comment: Thanks, What I was wondering was whether that was the best way or a hack that would allow accessing the variable via defining an unnecessary function. But this answers my question

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what you want is [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor):

```
class Commodity
  attr_accessor :xau
end
```

Which is essentially equivalent to this:

```
class Commodity
  def xau
    @xau
  end
  def xau=(value)
    @xau = value
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to do, but it looks like you want to do this:

```
class Commodity
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @xau = Commodity::PriceSeries.new(name)
  end
end
```

Then,

```
gold = Commodity.new("gold")
```

will automatically define

```
Commodity::PriceSeries.new("gold")
```

as the value of an instance variable `@xau` of `gold`.